# Convert List of Ints to a SortedSet in Scala

Tags: scala, sortedset

If I have a List of Ints like:

`val myList = List(3,2,1,9)`

what is the right/preferred way to create a SortedSet from a List or Seq of Ints, where the items are sorted from least to greatest?

If you held a gun to my head I would have said:

`val itsSorted = collection.SortedSet(myList)`

but I get an error regarding that there is no implicit ordering defined for List[Int].

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use:

```
collection.SortedSet(myList: _*)
```

The way you used it, the compiler thinks you want to create a `SortedSet[List[Int]]` not a `SortedSet[Int]`. That's why it complains about no implicit Ordering for `List[Int]`.

Notice the repeated parameter of type `A*` in the signature of the method:

```
def apply [A] (elems: A*)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): SortedSet[A]
```

To treat `myList` as a sequence argument of `A` use, the `_*` type annotation.

Comment: I had hoped that apply had an overload to take a collection/iterable of type x. In hindsight how could it. I haven't told it what type of SortedSet I want.

Answer (score 13):

You could also take advantage of the `CanBuildFrom` instance, and do this:

```
val myList = List(3,2,1,9)
myList.to[SortedSet]
// scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 9)
```

Comment: The recommended way is now myList.iterator.to[SortedSet]

Comment: `val myLista = List(3,2,1,9)
  myLista.iterator.to[SortedSet]` does not compile: `trait SortedSet takes type parameters
  myLista.iterator.to[SortedSet]`

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't seem to be a constructor that directly accepts `List` (correct me if I'm wrong). But you can easily write

```
val myList = List(3,2,1,9)
val itsSorted = collection.SortedSet.empty[Int] ++ myList
```

to the same effect. (See http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_20.html.)

Comment: This is the solution that I finally stumbled upon earlier. It just doesn't feel idiomatic :)

Comment: Nice solution, avoids the need to explicitly bring in an implicit ordering. I think it is not that the solution is not idiomatic as that the scala collections library does not provide the developer with an idiomatic api. Which is rather unfortunate for scala.

Answer (score 3):

This is especially useful if you have to map anyway:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

val s: collection.SortedSet[Int] = List(1,2,3,4).map(identity)(breakOut)
//--> s: scala.collection.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2, 3, 4)
```